How to remove \marginpar from automatically numbered paragraphs?
New member, first question:
I have found Fully automatic numbering of paragraphs to be very helpful.
I would like to not include numbering on \marginpar , \paragraph , and \subparagraph etc
In the above link's answer the lines:
\pretocmd{\@ssect}{\boolfalse{myparbool}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@ssect}{\booltrue{myparbool}}{}{}

ssect refers to \subsection (incorrect - see W.W. comment below)
What would refer to: \marginpar , \paragraph , and \subparagraph ?
Where can I find references on this (the etoolbox package .pdf does not have this information)
----- some answers:

The LATEX 2ε Sources - is a robust reference.(understatement)

\@footnotemark works in the above command (so footnotes are not numbered)

\@mn@@@marginnote works in the above for \marginnote



Welcome to TeX.SE, please use the editor to mark code as such.

Your reading of the original code is incorrect, the \@ssect means "starred sectioning commands", and the \@sect means "sectioning commands.

code in question marked as suggested

First, the reason that Simon Dispa's answer patches both \@sect and \@ssect is not to handle \section and \subsection separately. Indeed, you will notice that the code as it is also works just fine with \subsubsection, while no call to \@sssect (which doesn't exist) is made.
The \@sect and \@ssect refers to sectioning of un-starred (so numbered) and starred (so unnumbered) sections (in the generalized sense).
The reason that this doesn't work for \paragraph and \subparagraph is slightly complicated. Basically, the distinction is between how "hanging" section headings (like standard \section) and "run-in" headings (like standard "\paragraph") are coded. For example, if you take Simon Dispa's code and run it in the amsart document class, where \subsection uses "run-in" style, you will find that it also breaks for \subsection! To implement a "run-in" style, for various technical reasons, latex.ltx stores the section heading in the macro \@svsechd and prints it at the beginning of the subsequent paragraph. But this means that when the heading is printed it is after \@sect or \@ssect has already completed and hence the boolean flag has been reset to true.
Staring at the code in latex.ltx I cannot see an obvious way to use etoolbox patches to insert the boolean flag changes at the appropriate spots. However, we can leverage the boolean flags already built-in to latex.ltx that enables the logic for the "run-in" headings. So this means that we should modify the para/begin hook to also test for run-in headings, and disable the counter in those cases. This can be accomplished by changing the relevant line to
\AddToHook{para/begin}
{\if@noskipsec\else\ifbool{myparbool}{\stepcounter{mypar}\llap{\P\themypar\quad}}{}\fi}
% \if@noskipsec evaluates to true if we have a run-in heading to print

The problem with \marginpar is much easier to fix. At the beginning of every \marginpar the \@marginparreset macro is called. So you can just add the setting of the boolean flag there via
\apptocmd{\@marginparreset}{\boolfalse{myparbool}}{}{}

Full MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % Also works with amsart AFAICT

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newbool{myparbool}
\booltrue{myparbool}
\newcounter{mypar}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{para/begin}
{\if@noskipsec\else\ifbool{myparbool}{\stepcounter{mypar}\llap{\P\themypar\quad}}{}\fi}
\makeatother

%**************************** added <<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@ssect}{\boolfalse{myparbool}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@ssect}{\booltrue{myparbool}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@sect}{\boolfalse{myparbool}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@sect}{\booltrue{myparbool}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@marginparreset}{\boolfalse{myparbool}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section{First}
    
    All paragraphs should be numbered in the left margin but sections and subsections should not have paragraph numbers. This works but needs explicit manual control.
    
    \lipsum[1]

    \paragraph Test paragraph

    \subparagraph Test subparagraph

    \subsection{Second}

    \lipsum[2]
    
    \subsubsection{Third}

    \lipsum[3]

    Test \marginpar{A}

    \marginpar{B}
    
    \section*{Fourth}

    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}


the above works only when \setsecnumdepth  is set to {subsubsection}, if it is only set to {subsection} then the unwanted autonumbering still applies (in my code)

Wait, you are using memoir? That is very important information that you should've mentioned. Different document classes often redefine how sectioning commands are handled (which is why I specifically pointed out that the above code works with the standard article and amsart classes). Since I don't use memoir at all I am not particularly motivated to figure out how to make this work for that class.

Incidentally, this is why this site often asks users to include MWEs; precisely to prevent this sort of problem.

the solutions above thankfully work with memoir. I can now appreciate the usefulenss of MWEs and will be sure to do so in the future. Where might I find this latex.ltx so I can also stare at it - to now solve the \endnote numbering?

@22fergy: it depends on your distribution. Within the base directory of where TeX is installed (mine is at /usr/share/texmf-dist; on *nix systems it tend to be somewhere similar) you can find the base format files in tex/latex/base/. You can find the base directory by looking at the command line outputs when you run pdflatex.
